# Getting class through web reference from web service in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, class, reference

Im making an assigment for school basicly in Visual Studio 2015 using C#.

I have a class library (.dll) named Person.
It owns few private properties, public get/set functions and constructors.

Created a Web Service that includes this class Person and added Person as reference into Web Service.

Now i created an ASP.NET project, used a Web Reference to add this WebService and added the include (using ...).

ASP.NET -> Web Service -> Class Person

WebService recognizes Person and works normaly with it.
Whole project ASP.NET recognizes Person, no error or such, but i cant use any of the public functions in class Person.
I can call WebService functions normaly in ASP.NET and they work fine.

Person person = new Person("Barrack","Obama",32);
^This works in WebService, but not in ASP.NET, tho it colors Person as it would recognize it. Why?

Comment: Did you need to add it as a web service reference? It's not clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you just need to add a normal reference.

Comment: Yes it needs to be a web service reference. Does the references from webservice apply also to ASP.NET? Cuz it appears it doesnt.

Comment: You add a web service reference when there's some externally hosted API that you want to connect to (two servers). It sounds like you simply have a single server that needs to reference a class library.